# How to move terraform resource in terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have custom resource defined in my terraform module:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "whatever" 
{
   ....
}
```

Turns out `whatever` is not good name, and I need to update it.

Classic way of doing it would be to login onto each environment and execute `terraform state mv`, however I have lots of environments, and no automation for such action.

How I can change name of resource without manually moving state (only through editing terraform modules and applying plans)?

Comment: why not just rename it? it will remove the old resource with the old name and replace it with the same resource with a new name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the explanation in the question, I guess your best bet would be to use the `moved` block [1]. So for example, in your case that would be:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "a_much_better_whatever" 
{
   ....
}

moved {
  from = aws_alb_target_group.whatever
  to   = aws_alb_target_group.a_much_better_whatever
}
```

EDIT: As @Matt Schuchard noted, the `moved` block is available only for Terraform versions `>=1.1.0`.

EDIT 2: As per @Martin Atkins' comments, changed the resource name to be the name of the resource **moving to** instead of **moving from**.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax

Comment: For sure the best path forward, but you should probably add the caveat that this is for TF >= 1.1.0.

Comment: I agree, I was thinking about that, I will update the answer. Thank you Matt.

Comment: A small note: in a real use of `moved`, the `resource` block should be named to match the `to` argument rather than the `from` argument, so this would be `resource "aws_alb_target_group" "a_much_better_whatever"` to get the desired effect.

Comment: (Not a huge deal since Terraform will report an error with the configuration exactly as currently written: you can't have a configured resource at the same address as the `from` of a `moved` block.)

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation, updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same situation.

My plan is to create the new resource group in Terraform, apply it, move the resources in the Azure portal to the new resource group, and then do terraform state mv to move the resources in terraform.
Yes, if you have a lot of resources  its boring.. but I guess I won't brake anything this way.